# How to hot-reload State fields?

Tags: flutter

How to hot-reload fields of a `State` subclass in Flutter?

I know that the modifying the initial value of fields isn't taken into account during hot-reload and that I can use hot-restart for them. But this is painfully slow.

Is there any way to ease the process?

A typical use-case would be animations, especially `AnimationController`. As it is stored inside a State field, but we usually want to iterate over its duration. Example:

```
class MyAnim extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAnimState createState() => _MyAnimState();
}

class _MyAnimState extends State<MyAnim> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

State provides a custom lifecycle hook for hot-reloads: `reassemble`

You can freely override that method to have custom hot-reload behaviors. Don't worry, this method will never be called in production.

With a small tweak you'd get the following:

```
class _MyAnimState extends State<MyAnim> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    _initializeFields();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _initializeFields() {
    animationController.duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  }

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    _initializeFields();
    super.reassemble();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Now, whenever you modify your State class, it will correctly update `AnimationController`'s duration.